# C# parse string to Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse string to create Func instance.

```cs
public class A
{
    public int fieldA { get; private set; }
    public bool fieldB { get; private set; }
    public List<int> fieldC { get; private set; }
}
```

Check the condition of the instance of `A` class with :

```
{
    "Type" : "A"
    "Condition" : "fieldA > 0 && fieldB == true"
}
```

Of course the format of a string can be modified, for easier parsing.

What I want to create is actually :

```cs
Func<A, bool> condition = a => a.fieldA > 0 && a.fieldB == true;
```

Parsing the `condition` string would not be very hard, but since there are so many `A` instances, using reflection whenever checking the condition would not be desirable. What I want to do is "construct" this function from string in advance and cache it somewhere, and call cached function when I want to check the condition.

Could you give my any advices?

Comment: I think there's a "dynamic LINQ" library, which _might_ do what you want. I don't think there are any shortcuts in the standard .NET libraries themselves though.

Comment: I would use (CSScript)[https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script] to compile the condition.

Comment: @LegacyCode your link is broken unfortunately mate. It says "404 this is not the page you are looking for"

Comment: How do you obtain the condition? Is it a constant and present from the start of the program or do you get it as some input from network etc.?

Comment: @Ackdari I will read it from files in the start of the program

Comment: @MyBug18 then why don't you just code it hard into a static util class or even the `A` class? Why does it need to be configurable after compiling the program?

Comment: @Ackdari I want my code to be highly modifiable, without compiling repeatedly. And also there will be bunch of files, which will be removed and added many times. Compiling it every time would be reaaaaallly tediuos...

Comment: You could either use the [`Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netcore-3.1) class or the runtime [compiler](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RuntimeCompilation.aspx) to achive what you want.

Comment: I didn't try but [this](https://github.com/AndreVianna/ExpressionParser) may help

Comment: @Mong Zhu - Sorry the link was not correctly formatted https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) you could do something like:

```
public bool TestCondition(A obj, string condition)
{
    var expr = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<A, bool>(ParsingConfig.Default, false, condition, new object[0]);
    var func = expr.Compile();
    return func(obj);
}
```

And invoke it like:

```
var testResult = TestCondition(anInstanceOfA, "fieldA > 0 && fieldB == true");
```

If you want to use local variables in your expression you can do:

```
public static bool TestCondition(A obj, string condition, IDictionary<string, object> args)
{
    var expr = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new ParameterExpression[] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(A)) },
        typeof(bool),
        condition,
        new object[] { args });

    var func = expr.Compile();
    return (bool)func.DynamicInvoke(obj);
}
```

And invoke it like:

```
var locals = new Dictionary<string, object>();
locals.Add("myInt", 0);
locals.Add("myBool", true);
var check = TestCondition(obj, "fieldA > myInt && fieldB == myBool", locals);
```

You can also make the method generic so you can reuse it in other circumstances:

```
public static TOut TestCondition<TIn, TOut>(TIn obj, string condition, IDictionary<string, object> args)
{
    var expr = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new ParameterExpression[] { Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn)) },
        typeof(TOut),
        condition,
        new object[] { args });

    var func = expr.Compile();
    return (TOut)func.DynamicInvoke(obj);
}

.
.
.
TestCondition<A, bool>(obj, "fieldA > myInt && fieldB == myBool", locals)
```